# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable for DBscan

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dbscan

Data set is below

```
storeid,revenue,profit,country
101,11434,2345,IN
101,12132,3445,US
102,21343,4545,CH
103,34423,3432,CH
103,43435,3234,JP
103,34345,3335,IN
```

Code is below

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
from collections import Counter
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv',index_col=None)
df.head()
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data = df)
del dummies['Unnamed:0']
model = DBSCAN(eps = 2.25, min_samples=19).fit(dummies)
print (model)
target = dummies.iloc[:,0]
data = dummies.iloc[:,1:-1]
outliers_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (Counter(model.labels_))
print(outliers_df(model.labels_==-1))
```

`print(outliers_df(model.labels_==-1))` throwing TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `[]` for filter by mask:

```
print(outliers_df[model.labels_==-1]) 
   revenue  profit  country_CH  country_IN  country_JP
0    11434    2345           0           1           0
1    12132    3445           0           0           0
2    21343    4545           1           0           0
3    34423    3432           1           0           0
4    43435    3234           0           0           1
5    34345    3335           0           1           0
```